# CASE Expression within WHERE clause for different date fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to include a `case` expression within a `where` clause, to show all records depending on two forms of criteria. I'm getting lots of syntax errors with the below and wondering what I'm missing?

```
...
AND 
CASE WHEN (TypeName = 'Category1' or TypeName = 'Category2') THEN 
    Headers.HeaderDate < DATEADD(dd,1,@ReportDate)
ELSE
    Headers.TimeStamp < DATEADD(dd,1,@ReportDate)
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Case` is an expression not a statement and as such returns a value, not a condition, so you want

```
AND CASE WHEN (TypeName = 'Category1' OR TypeName = 'Category2')
  THEN Headers.HeaderDate ELSE Headers.TimeStamp END < DATEADD(dd,1,@ReportDate)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do it without using a case expression

```
and (
  (Typename in ('Category1','Category2') and Headers.HeaderDate < DATEADD(dd,1,@ReportDate)
  or (Typename not in ('Category1','Category2') and Headers.TimeStamp < DATEADD(dd,1,@ReportDate)
)
```

If `Typename` can be `null` you should also keep it in mind.